# Run a specific batch command in python

Tags: python, batch-file, module, python-3.3

What if I want to include a single batch command that isn't already in a file in python?

for instance:

```
REN *.TXT *.BAT
```

Could I put that in a python file somehow?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? rename all `.txt` files to `.bat`?

Answer (score 12):

The "old school" answer was to use [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). I'm not familiar with Windows but something like that would do the trick:

```
import os
os.system('ren *.txt *.bat')
```

Or (maybe)

```
import os
os.system('cmd /c ren *.txt *.bat')
```

---

But now, as noticed by Ashwini Chaudhary, the "recommended" [replacement for `os.system`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) is [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

If `REN` is a Windows shell *internal* command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ren *.txt *.bat', shell=True)
```

If it is an *external* command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ren *.txt *.bat')
```

Comment: Prefer `subprocess` module for such tasks and this is mentioned in the `os.system`'s docs as well.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary For "advanced" use (like capturing output) you are right. For basic usage, system does a decent job ;) Anyway, I'm not sure how will behave "subprocess" while invoking internal shell commands. You have to invoke `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`, right? I edit my answer accordingly. Thanks to pointing that out!

Comment: `shell = True` can be dangerous and is not recommended generally, use `shlex.split` : `subprocess.call(shlex.split('ren *.txt *.bat'))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I agree that `shell=True` could be dangerous when invoking user-provided commands ([shell command injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)) -- but I don't think we are in that situation here. The "shell command" seems to be provided by the programmer. And (I'm not sure about that) if 'REN' is actually an _internal_ Windows shell command -- you will need a shell.

Comment: `shell = True` doesn't means the command has to be a shell command, it is required when you're passing a single string to `subprocess`.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: I didn't look into the code, but as far as I understand `shell=True` execute the command in a sub-shell (like the old 'system') -- with all the corresponding risks of "shell injection" if the command originate somehow from user provided data. Without `shell=True` the command is directly invoked -- so without shell interpretation of multiple-commands, meta-characters and so on.

Comment: FWIW, the first example of the two ways work for me on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cmd /c ren *.txt *.bat
```

or

```
cmd /c "ren *.txt *.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

A example use subprocess for execute a command of Linux from Python:

```
mime = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/file -i " + sys.argv[1], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a `test.py` containing this, and it worked....

```
from subprocess import Popen    # now we can reference Popen
process = Popen(['cmd.exe','/c ren *.txt *.tx2'])
```